# Set "start" field to 0 in mp3 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to change the bitrate and sample rate of an MP3 to match another to try and stop a small audio glitch from occurring when some game tries to play it. I've got the sample rate and bitrate right where I want them, but I can't get the "start" portion of

```
  Duration: 00:03:33.81, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 196 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s
```

to go to 0, like the mp3 I'm trying to replace. The target looks like:

```
  Duration: 00:06:47.59, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 196 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s
```

I've tried a variety of silenceremove filters and -ss flags to try and trim it, but I can't get rid of that "start" field. Google is failing me. What args am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to change the bitrate and sample rate of an MP3 to match another to try and stop a small audio glitch from occurring when some game tries to play it.

Bitrate shouldn't matter.  For example, some MP3 streams use variable bitrate, where the bitrate can actually change from frame to frame.  Matching sample rate may be important, depending on your specific use case, but sounds unlikely.

In any case, the easiest thing to do is convert that MP3 to a WAV, edit the file exactly how you want it, and compress again back to an MP3.  This is pretty much what you're doing now, but you're likely running up into imprecise timing due to the framing.

Note that the best thing to do is go back to the original files, if they're available.  Every time you try to edit and re-compress, you're losing quality.

Comment: Unfortunately the weird format the game expects has a lot of caveats. For instance, one song I replaced was originally 48khz and the mp3 I replaced it with was 44.1khz, and it played somewhat sped up when in game. I haven't actually noticed any differences with bitrate, but I'm trying to eliminate differences. There's a sudden burst of static at the beginning of the track in game and I'm trying to eliminate that last difference. The song *sounds* exactly how I want, except from the static at the beginning, and I've been unable to get rid of that "start: 0.25057".

Comment: Sounds more likely that the decoder doesn't know how to handle ID3 tags.  Try stripping those out.

Comment: Removing the ID3 tags doesn't improve the situation. What's more, the screech at the beginning is a bit harsher now and my game crashes after playing a few of the beginning notes of the song. I might just drop this and accept that EA just has to be weird and use their own reimplementation of mp3. The game I'm working on is Burnout Paradise and it's their weird SNS file format with ealayer3 as the codec.